# Contour integral over a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

The circle has centre 0.5 and radius 0.25 and is traversed once anticlockwise.

the function $$\frac {z+1} {z(z-1)(z-3)}$$

needs to be integrated.

Ive used the path given by $$0.5+\frac14 e^{it}$$

for t between 0 and 2pi

I then used partial fracitons to arrive at three integrals added together with bounds 2pi and 0  $$\int \frac 1 {0.5+ 0.25e^{it}} +\int \frac 1 {-2.5+ 0.25e^{it}}+  \int \frac 1 {-0.5+ 0.25e^{it}} $$

But I'm unsure how to integrate any of these integrals. I've used online calculators and they give $$-0.4t -0.4iln(|10-e^{it}|)$$
But when I use substitution I only get $$-0.4iln( |10-e^{it}|)$$

Is my current work correct? and if it isn't where did I go wrong and how should I attempt the question.

Comment: Does the problem allow using the Cauchy integral theorem?

Comment: I expect they would allow it.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $\frac{z+1}{z(z-1)(z-3)}$ is $\Bbb C\setminus\{0,1,3\}$. Since the domain contains the closed disk with center $\frac12$ and radius $\frac14$, whose boundary is the circle that you are interested in, your integral is equal to $0$, by Cauchy's integral theorem.